# Call function received as a parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code with a function:

```
var f1;

var getFunction = function (f2) {
    f1 = f2;   
}
```

Later in the code, I need to call `f1` (that was actually received as a parameter). Note that I don't know the function's name when I call it.

How do I make this call?

Comment: so you call it... `f1();`

Comment: `getFunction( f2 ); f1(); //where f2 is a function`

Comment: Later in the code where? Why don't you know the name? By your example, you know it's either `f1` or `f2`. Did you try something and experience failure? Is there something async involved? The question is very unclear.

Comment: Your current code works so what's the problem...

Comment: When you assign a function to `f1`, guess what... its name is `f1`.

Comment: @deceze not true, functions have a name property : `var func = function hello(){};
console.log(func.name)`

Comment: @Kaiido: Do you honestly not understand the point he was making?

Comment: @Kaiido *...a name by which you can call the function is...* – I was trying to keep it simple and straight forward. There isn't a lot of space in comments to list all caveats and asterisks and it doesn't make it easier to understand either.

Comment: @deceze: Next time please just include the full content of the ES7 spec with your comment for clarity. :D

Comment: @squint Sure, will do. 

Comment: "*Do you honestly not understand the point he was making?*" If we're talking about being rude to the OP making him looks like an idiot, yes I see it, otherwise, I don't see what this comment tells that the first one doesn't (except the wrong assertion I pointed out if we take the words strictly).

Comment: @Kaiido: Informality is acceptable in informal settings. We're not at a TC39 meeting, and nobody (including the OP) is discussing the built-in properties of function objects. We're communicating with the OP using the OP's terms for the OP's sake, who apparently needs to know how to reference the function, which won't be done by the `.name` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function test(){
     alert(1);
}
var f1;

var getFunction = function (f2) {
    f1 = f2; 
    f1();  
}

getFunction(test);
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9u9v4nf7/)

Answer (score 1):

This is no different than callbacks in Ajax call or anywhere else where you pass around a reference to a function. You just execute it via the variable that you store the function in.

```js
var f1;

var setFunction = function (f2) {
    f1 = f2;   
}

setFunction( function(x) { console.log(x); } );

f1("test");
```

If you need to execute it with scope, than you need to use `.apply()` or `.call()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var f1;

var getFunction = function (f2) {
    f1 = f2;   
}
var b = function(){}
getFunction(b);
f1();
```

Comment: Could you provide some context to your answer, explaining how it works and addresses the question?